# Javascript ES6 - Check if a Symbol is available in global registry without creating it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

Is it possible to check if a symbol is available in global registory?

What I do:

```
global[Symbol.for('childoftheelderblood')] = true;
//In another file/window/universe
if(!global[Symbol.for('childoftheelderblood')]) console.error('Sorry, but your Ciri is in another universe');
```

What if `global` is not available in the parallel universe? Only symbols are cross-dimensional and universal. Can I somehow check if a symbol has been created in the global registry without actually creating it like `Symbol.for` does.

Comment: Why not just add an array/object in the global repository with the value/key equal to the string that you are using to create the symbol. Later just check if that string exists in the global repository’s array/object. Something like `global.symbols ={ ‘childoftheelderblood’: true}`

Comment: I think I outlined the reason fairly clearly - I do not want to rely on an implicit dependency of having a namespace named `global` or any other for that matter. In fact in the parallel universe a namespace called `global` might have a completely different and important purpose and must not be disturbed! Or it could be a proxy under that name, which secretly sacrifises an infant to the Eternal Fire every time one accesses it's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if a symbol is available in global registry?

No. Symbols in the global registry are not "created", they're fetched from it. You can imagine that the registry already contains all possible symbols - though of course they are created lazily (as needed) in the real implementation.

The global symbol registry is not a communication channel<sup>1</sup>. It cannot be mutated. All it does is provide access to common symbols so that they can be used as properties of shared objects.

If you have multiple realms and you want to pass the `childoftheelderblood = true` bit between them, you need to do so explicitly using shared buffers, storage, or messaging as provided by your environment.

<sub>1: If it was, that would be a huge security hole which enables leaking information</sub>

Comment: This sees to contradict with
"The Symbol.for(key) method searches for existing symbols in a runtime-wide symbol registry with the given key and returns it if found. Otherwise a new symbol gets *created* in the global symbol registry with this key."
But otherwise seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Megakoresh Yeah, that's a sub-optimal description. I would consider it an implementation detail - but the interface is really that you're asking for a symbol with that name, and there is no state of the registry in which you don't get it.